# How to make Tensorflow load GPU higher?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have Tensorflow 1.4 GPU version installed. It successfully detects my GPU and uses it while trainig and evaluating. I have GeForce 1050Ti with 4Gb memory.

But I could not reach GPU load higher that 12-15% (more usual 5-6%). Meanwhile I get high CPU load and pretty slow training process.
I tested many different examples of differen NNs (RNN, LSTM, CNN, GAN etc) with plain Tensorflow and with Keras with TF as backend, but the result is the same.

I found that increasing a batch size helps to load GPU more, but batch size also affects training itself, so I can't increase it more than some possible limits.

So how to use GPU at maximum load and speed-up the NN training?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Keras in ubuntu, you can *use multiprocessing* and increase number of *workers*. If you use Batch Generator then you can increase *limit on sequence* depending upon the system RAM you have.

```
model.fit_generator(..., max_queue_size = 24, ..., workers = 2, use_multiprocessing = True, ...)
```